# Edit Facebook post with C#?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Im using this code to post to a facebook feed :

```
 public string UploadPost(string intTitle, string inMessage, string inLinkCaption, int inLinkUrl, string inLinkDescription, string inLinkUrlPicture)
    {
        object obj;
        Facebook.JsonObject jsonObj;
        FacebookClient client;
        string access_token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageAccessToken"].ToString();

        client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

        var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        args["message"] = inMessage;
        args["caption"] = inLinkCaption;
        args["description"] = inLinkDescription;
        args["name"] = intTitle;
        args["picture"] = inLinkUrlPicture;
        args["link"] = inLinkUrl;

        if((obj = client.Post("/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookPageId"].ToString() + "/feed", args)) != null)
        {
            if((jsonObj = obj as Facebook.JsonObject) != null)
            {
                if(jsonObj.Count > 0)
                    return jsonObj[0].ToString();
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Is it possible to edit this post after the creation with the post Id from prev method or will I have to delete it and post it as a new post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit an existing post, you'll have to delete the existing and post a new one. 
[See Facebook documentation link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/post#updating)